Sort JSON/Map structure in clojure before serializing to string
I'm using json/write-str to serialize a nested JSON object to string.
Example data:
{ :c 1 :a { :d 0 :c 1 :e { :a 0 :1 4 }}}
; json/write-str
; output
{"c":1,"a":{"d":0,"c":1,"e":{"a":0,"1":4}}}

Expected output
{"a":{"c":1,"d":0,"e":{"1":4,"a":0}},"c":1}

This can be trivially solved in JavaScript with the second parameter into the JSON.stringify function, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for Clojure.

Worth noting that according to the spec a JSON object is "an unordered set of name/value pairs" (emphasis mine). Even if you sort when serializing there's no guarantee it's preserved when parsing it back, regardless of language. If order matters, use something else (e.g. a vector of key, value tuples).

It is also handy sometimes to use an ordered-map or set, which maintains the insertion order of entries. You can insert keys/values into the map based on priority (not necessarily alphabetical), and they will print out in the same order.

The problem is that you have hash maps in your data and the order of elements is undefined there. You have to make sure all the maps in your data are sorted-map and the simplest way do so is to recursively replace all maps by sorted maps:

(require '[clojure.walk :refer [postwalk]])

(def sort-maps
  (partial postwalk (fn [x]
                      (if (map? x)
                        (into (sorted-map) x)
                        x))))

(def data {:c 1 :a {:d 0 :c 1 :e {:a 0 :1 4}}})

(sort-maps data)
;; result: {:a {:c 1, :d 0, :e {:1 4, :a 0}}, :c 1}

(json/generate-string (sort-maps data))
;; "{\"a\":{\"c\":1,\"d\":0,\"e\":{\"1\":4,\"a\":0}},\"c\":1}"



in this exact case you could also use built in :value-fn option of that lib:
user=> (defn smap [data] (if (map? data) (into (sorted-map) data) data))
#'user/smap

user=> (json/write-str (smap data) :value-fn #(smap %2))
"{\"a\":{\"c\":1,\"d\":0,\"e\":{\"1\":4,\"a\":0}},\"c\":1}"


user=> (json/write-str (smap {:x 10 :b {:c 20 :a {:9 100 :3 101}}}) :value-fn #(smap %2))
"{\"b\":{\"a\":{\"3\":101,\"9\":100},\"c\":20},\"x\":10}"

but notice, that it only works on map values (e.g. it will not sort maps inside an array).
so the walk solution from another answer is more versatile.
there are more handy opts applicable in the docs
